# AWS Cognito and FB login

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm getting my feet wet with AWS Cognito. I'm trying to create a simple HTML page which allows user to signup using their facebook account.

I have set up an Identity Pool in de AWS Cognito console, and specified the correct app-id in the FaceBook Provider setting.

I now created the following html page, which is hosted on S3. The authentication step via FaceBook works ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.4.12.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1'; // Region
      AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        Logins: {
        'graph.facebook.com': response.authResponse.accessToken
      }
      });
      console.log(AWS.config);
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, When I check the identity browser in the Cognito console, I don't see any users after they logged in via FaceBook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually need to get the credentials from the service after updating the params for the credentials.

`AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {...});` is one way to do it.

Here are some blog posts which can help you setup the code for JavaScript SDK.

1. https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxBVEDL5Z8JKAC/Use-Amazon-Cognito-in-your-website-for-simple-AWS-authentication
2. https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/TxTUNTVES4AL15/Authentication-in-the-Browser-with-Amazon-Cognito-and-Public-Identity-Providers
3. https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/Tx1F7FO6GDAIXD3/Authentication-with-Amazon-Cognito-in-the-Browser